# Using the haskell map function with a string

Tags: haskell, dictionary

I'm trying to use the map function in haskell

I've got this:

```
lexi :: String -> [[String]]
lexi x = map (words.lines) x
```

I want to be able to put a string in to x, so it can be run like this

```
lexi ("string here")
```

But get the error

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
Expected type: String -> String
  Actual type: String -> [String]
In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘lines’
In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(words . lines)’

Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
Expected type: [String]
  Actual type: String
In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘x’
In the expression: map (words . lines) x
```

I know that if I use

```
lexi = map (words.lines)
```

it works fine when I run `lexi ("string here")`, but need the variable to use later on

Could some please explain why this doesn't work and how to fix it?

Thank you :)

Comment: What is the type of function? is it `Char -> Char` or `Char -> String`?

Comment: I want it to take a String, and the function that is being used in the map will return a [String]

Comment: if function has type `String -> [String]` then `map function` will have type `[String] -> [[String]]`. Are you sure you want map?

Comment: I've updated the question to try and make it clearer

Comment: What do you want `lexi` to do?

Comment: I hope I've edited the question to make it clear now, but basically I want to split a string based on new lines and spaces whilst storing the output to a variable in a function, I can get it running without using a variable but as soon as I try to add one it breaks

Answer (score 4):

### *This answer refers to [an old version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26971787/2)*.

So let's get this quite clear (please *always* add the type signature of all functions you're talking about!)

```
function :: Char -> [String]
```

Well, then the type of `map function` is `[Char] -> [[String]]`, i.e. `String -> [[String]]`. But you want the result to be only `[String]`, not a triply-nested list. You probably want to join the lists of two levels together; in general the function to use for list-joining purposes is `concat` (or more generally, `join` from the `Control.Monad` module). In this case, you have two different options:

- Join the result of each call to `function`. I.e., instead of mapping `function` alone, you map `join . function`, which has type `Char -> String`. Mapping that has the desired type `String -> [String]`.

  ```
  lexi = map $ join . function
  ```
- Join the final result of the mapping, i.e. `lexi = join . map function`. This combination of mapping and joining the results is actually an extremely common task, it has a special operator: monadic bind!

  ```
  lexi x = x >>= function
  ```

### New version

So we know that

```
words, lines :: String -> [String]
```

thus `words . lines` can not work, because you're trying to feed a list of strings into a function that only accepts a single string. What you can of course do though is *map* `words` over the result, i.e. `map words . lines`. That has in fact the correct signature and probably does just what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just a few questions, is the >>= operator assigning the function to x? 
And the join function, turns the double list into a single list?
Also I've made my question clearer now, so sorry about the initial ambiguity

Comment: That edit unfortunately changed the meaning of the entire question. Please try to avoid this kind of confusion in the future. — The `>>=` works kind of like a swapped `$` function-application operator. We can actually write it the other way around: `f =<< list ≡ join (map f list)` i.e. it'll first map `f` over the list, then join the results together.